# Rename Visual Studio 2017 RC in "Open with" menu after upgrading to RTM

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, registry, modern-ui

I figured this one out, so answer incoming.

After upgrading Visual Studio 2017 RC to RTM, it bugged me that the Open with menu in Windows still shows the old application name.
[image: Image of Visual Studio misnamed in Windows Open with context menu]

My understanding is upgrading from RC to RTM is officially supported. Opening the application and rebooting the computer both had no effect. So, why doesn't the name get changed?

Answer (score 0):

I searched the registry and found the old application name in the MUICache under HKCU. Apparently Windows stores names there for performance reasons.

If you don't want to edit the registry manually, you may also use a tool from NirSoft called [MUICacheView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/muicache_view.html) to edit it.

There is a String value under this registry key which contains the old name:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\MuiCache
```

In my case I found the String value data of `Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 RC` and changed it to `Microsoft Visual Studio 2017`.

This fixed it immediately.

[image: Image of Visual Studio fixed in Windows Open with context menu]